# Add comment for only one post in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

My question about comment in wordpress. I have a website, and I want user visit my website and only comment on a unique post. My website is: diendansuckhoe.vn and i want to comment in only and only this post: http://diendansuckhoe.vn/phong-kham-da-khoa-3-thang-2/ . Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Please explain me, why my question is not useful.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Please post some code you would like help with.

Comment: thank, because i search in internet and i see this website can help me, so i post this question on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by disallowing comments on all other posts, and allowing them only on post of your choice.

First click on "Screen Options" and Make sure you have "Discussion" selected

[image]

then, scroll to bottom and find comments:

[image]

Just uncheck this on posts where you don't want your comments to show.

Comment: my website have no comment function in creen Options

Comment: Sorry, my fault, under "Screen Options" make sure "Discussion" is selected. Then scroll bottom and check/uncheck comments for each post.